# Connecting Jenkins to AWS CodeCommit Repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, aws-codecommit

I have deployed a local Jenkins server (Windows host) and am attempting to connect to a repo in Amazon's AWS CodeCommit service. 
I have configured the AWS CodeDeploy credentials in Jenkins (via the AWS CodeDeploy Plugin) with my AWS Access Key and Secre Key.

I have created a new freestyle project, and have selected Git under Source Code Management and configirued:
Repository URL - copied the SSH url from AWS Code Commit console
Credentials - I have created a global credential and pointed it to my private key, and entered the passphrase.

When configuring the Repo URL the following error is displayed:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h
>   ssh://[REMOVED]@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/[REMOVED]/
>   HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: Permission denied
>   (publickey).  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Seems like a simple access error but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. If I open my git bash and paste the above command in, I am presented with:

> You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to
>   interact with AWS CodeCommit. Connection to
>   git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote host. fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

So It seems that the SSH connection is working. 
When I run:

```
ssh -vT [REMOVED]@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I get the following output:

> You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to
>   interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not
>   supported.debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
>   Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com closed by remote
>   host. Transferred: sent 4160, received 2368 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
>   Bytes per second: sent 24893.3, received 14170.0 debug1: Exit status
>   -1

So it seems I really can access Code Commit okay.

I have also verified that my IAM user is able to connect to CodeCommit by attached the CodeCommitFullAccess policy. I have also cloned the repo using git bash, on the Windows host running Jenkins.

Does anyone know how I can get Jenkins to connect without displaying the error?

Comment: what user is Jenkins running under?

Comment: Are you able to connect to other git services with ssh from that jenkins box?

Comment: @Mircea - Its on windows so just my Windows account.

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko - I've been able to clone the CodeCommit repo using git from this box - if that is waht you are asking. It is just the Jenkins connection that fails to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in your question that you are using a passphrase for your SSH key.  It looks like this is a known issue with Jenkins that has not been resolved as of now: [JENKINS-20879](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879).  I see some workarounds for Unix platforms, but not for Windows.  You might consider creating an SSH key for Jenkins that does not have a passphrase to work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks. In the end we have simply deployed an EC2 instance hosting Jenkins, but glad to notice I wasn't going crazy.